# How to model parse-server schema with client class creation disabled

Tags: schema, parse-server

Is accessing the `/parse/schemas` endpoint the only way of defining a model with client class creation disabled? I wonder if there is a way to pre-populate the model on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the parse dashboard, or a Node.js client with the masterKey.

This way you can create / initialize your Models with the comfort of your browser or terminal.